# iOS: Custom transitioningDelegate doesn't work

Tags: ios, segue, uiviewanimationtransition

This is my custom transitioningDelegate:

```
enum CameraState {
    case On
    case Off
}

class CameraTransitioning: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    var state: CameraState

    init(state: CameraState) {
        self.state = state
    }

    func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()
        let fromVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
        let toVC = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)
        let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)
        let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)

        var toViewInitialFrame = transitionContext.initialFrameForViewController(toVC!)
        var fromViewFinalFrame = transitionContext.finalFrameForViewController(fromVC!)
        switch self.state {
        case .On:
            toViewInitialFrame.origin.y = containerView!.frame.height
        case .Off:
            fromViewFinalFrame.origin.y = -containerView!.frame.height
        }

        containerView?.addSubview(toView!)
        toView?.frame = toViewInitialFrame

        let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
            fromView?.frame = fromViewFinalFrame
            }) {
                finished in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        }
    }
    func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
        return 10
    }

    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }
    func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Home -> Camera" {
        let cameraVC = segue.destinationViewController as! CameraViewController
        cameraVC.delegate = self
        cameraVC.transitioningDelegate = CameraTransitioning(state: .On)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use this transitioning because I don't like the default UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut, and I have tried to set the duration to 10 to make this change clear. But this doesn't work. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `transitioningDelegate` property is weak, and you are creating no other strong references to it. Something else needs to own that object for it to stick around long enough to be used to animate the transition.

Comment: It is probably the right answer but I still do not get it :(. I have created an instance of the transitionof the transition as a property of the from view controller and it is still not used. Any recommendation of what should "own" the instance of the animator when transitionning? thanks for any help.

Comment: @AlexandreRoba probably best asking a new question